# CString to Short in vc++

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

How to convert CString value into Short in VC++.

```
CString str;
Short sdata;
void CStringToShort(){

    ..........
    .........

}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you search for *any* string (not just specifically `CString`) to integer conversion functions?

Comment: [Convert-CString-to-short](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/282823/Convert-CString-to-short)

Comment: Is `Short` (big S) a typedef for something, or did you mean `short`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
CString str;
Short sdata;
_stscanf(str, _T("%d"), &sdata);
```

Or

```
sdata = _ttoi(str);
sdata = _wtoi(str);
```

Comment: `%d` expects an `int`-sized storage location, while you are providing a `Short`-sized storage location. This may well crash, if you're lucky, or otherwise corrupt your stack.